# Number of regular (not necessarily simple) polygons on $n$ equidistant points on a circle.

Tags: combinatorics, polygons

I need to find the number of regular $n$-polygons on $n$ equidistant points on a circle (that is, adjacent points are equally distant from each other). There's a hint saying the answer is related to the totient function.

What confuses me is that this question was given after we studied linear recurrence relations, and I can't think of any way to use them here.

The only thing I can think of is that we have such an $n$-polygon precisely when every $1\leq k\leq n$ coprime to $n$, and then divide by two because we count each such polygon twice...

Comment: It's not entirely clear whether regular star polygons are allowed, and how disjoint polygons are counted e.g. 1 vs. 2 equilateral triangles for the regular hexagon.

Comment: @dxiv edited - only talking about $n$-gons.

Comment: You seem to have the idea in picking a stride $k$ coprime to $n$, e.g. $k=1$ or $k=n-1$ both give the regular convex $n$-gon.  Naturally we expect $n\ge 3$ to avoid triviality, but perhaps you wish to include some words about the degenerate cases $n=1,2$.

Comment: Note that conveniently $\phi(n)$ is always even for $n\ge 3$.

Comment: @hardmath cool. Would you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Let $v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1}$ be equally spaced points wrapping around a circle in consecutive order.  In how many ways can a regular polygonal path connect them all in a circuit?

If $n=1,2$ then no nondegenerate polygon (or circuit) is possible, so assume $n\ge 3$.

By regularity the chords connecting any pair of the points $v_i,v_j$ in a circuit will all have the same length and subtend equal central angles.  This means there exists $1 \le k \lt n$ such that $j = (i+k) \bmod n$.

There are two claims to show, that such $k$ is coprime to $n$ and that $k_1$ and $k_2$ correspond to the same polygonal edges just when $k_2 = n - k_1$.

For the first of these note that if $d = \gcd(k,n)$, then only $n/d$ edges (chords) are needed to form a circuit from $v_0$ back to itself.  In order for the circuit to include all $n$ points, we require $d=1$.  Thus $k,n$ are coprime.

Thus there are $\phi(n)$ possibilities for $k$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.

Finally two distinct "strides" $k_1,k_2$ around the circle give different polygons exactly when chords subtend unequal angles and have different lengths.  Otherwise $k_1 + k_2 = n$ and we get equal chord lengths.  Note that since $k$ is coprime to $n$, we never have $k = n-k$.

This establishes the second claim, so that the number of coprimes $k$ to $n$ counts each regular polygonal circuit exactly twice.

Thus the number of regular polygonal circuits is $\phi(n)/2$, and for the sake of specificity we could always choose the lesser of $k$ and $n-k$ to describe the circuit.

In effect this proves in a geometric/combinatorial fashion that $\phi(n)$ is always even for $n\ge 3$, by virtue of this correspondence of polygons.  However the same may easily be argued by number theory.  If $n$ has an odd prime factor $p$, then $p-1$ is a factor of $\phi(n)$ (and thus even). Otherwise for $n\ge 3$ not to have an odd prime factor it must be that $n=2^m$ for $m\gt 1$, and again $\phi(n) = 2^{m-1}$ is even.